# HTML Elements wrapping on zoom in / out

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, text

I have list of screen names that can be filtered by letter. The Issue I am having is that when the browser window is zoomed out anywhere from 1-5 levels the z will wrap to the nextline in firefox and several letters will wrap in chrome. zoomed 5 levels out seems ok in IE. Here is the sample source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .filters { position: absolute; background: #ff0000 0 0 no-repeat; width: 970px; height: 31px; left: 0; text-transform: uppercase; }
    .letters { float: left; margin: 2px 0 0 7px; width: 710px; height: 30px; background-color: orange;  }
    .screenname {width: 244px; background-color: green; float: left; }
    .filters .letters a { display: inline; margin: 0 14px 0 0; }
    .filters .letters a.disabled { color: #36373a; cursor: default; }
    .filters a { font: bold italic 12px/28px Arial, sans-serif; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="filters">
        <div class="screenname">
            Screen Name
        </div>
        <div class="letters">
            <a href="#" rel="#">#</a>
            <a href="#" rel="A">A</a>
            <a href="#" rel="B">B</a>
            <a href="#" rel="C">C</a>
            <a href="#" rel="D">D</a>
            <a href="#" rel="E">E</a>
            <a href="#" rel="F">F</a>
            <a href="#" rel="G">G</a>
            <a href="#" rel="H">H</a>
            <a href="#" rel="I">I</a>
            <a href="#" rel="J">J</a>
            <a href="#" rel="K">K</a>
            <a href="#" rel="L">L</a>
            <a href="#" rel="M">M</a>
            <a href="#" rel="N">N</a>
            <a href="#" rel="O">O</a>
            <a href="#" rel="P">P</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Q">Q</a>
            <a href="#" rel="R">R</a>
            <a href="#" rel="S">S</a>
            <a href="#" rel="T">T</a>
            <a href="#" rel="U">U</a>
            <a href="#" rel="V">V</a>
            <a href="#" rel="W">W</a>
            <a href="#" rel="X">X</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Y">Y</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Z">Z</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now put that in an HTML file and zoom out (Ctrl-) five times in both chrome and firefox. You'll see wrapping occurs. How can I avoid this? I can't increase the size of the filters div and I can see that the issue may be partially caused by the font rendering in chrome (it stops decreasing in size after a certain number of zooms). I'm open to any javascript/Jquery hacks that might work also.

Comment: Is this really that important? If someone's zoomed out 5 times I'm pretty sure they won't even be able to read the letters, much less care if it's wrapped.

Comment: If it wasn't something important I wouldn't have wasted my time asking. Luckily someone else took the time to come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only wrapping I get is the Z going onto a new line at a few zoom increments on Firefox. Chrome and IE seem to work fine for me.

Something you could do is increase the width of the `.letters` class.

What I would probably do in order to have more control over the exact width of the `.letters a` tags is change them to float and explicitly state the width like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .filters { position: absolute; background: #ff0000 0 0 no-repeat; width: 970px; height: 31px; left: 0; text-transform: uppercase; }
    .letters { float: left; margin: 2px 0 0 7px; width: 710px; height: 30px; background-color: orange;  }
    .screenname {width: 244px; background-color: green; float: left; }
    /* flooat(710 / 27) = 26px  */
    .filters .letters a { float:left; display:block; text-align:center; width:26px; }
    /* fix offset */
    .filters .letters a:first-child { margin-left:8px; }
    .filters .letters a.disabled { color: #36373a; cursor: default; }
    .filters a { font: bold italic 12px/28px Arial, sans-serif; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="filters">
        <div class="screenname">
            Screen Name
        </div>
        <div class="letters">
            <a href="#" rel="#">#</a>
            <a href="#" rel="A">A</a>
            <a href="#" rel="B">B</a>
            <a href="#" rel="C">C</a>
            <a href="#" rel="D">D</a>
            <a href="#" rel="E">E</a>
            <a href="#" rel="F">F</a>
            <a href="#" rel="G">G</a>
            <a href="#" rel="H">H</a>
            <a href="#" rel="I">I</a>
            <a href="#" rel="J">J</a>
            <a href="#" rel="K">K</a>
            <a href="#" rel="L">L</a>
            <a href="#" rel="M">M</a>
            <a href="#" rel="N">N</a>
            <a href="#" rel="O">O</a>
            <a href="#" rel="P">P</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Q">Q</a>
            <a href="#" rel="R">R</a>
            <a href="#" rel="S">S</a>
            <a href="#" rel="T">T</a>
            <a href="#" rel="U">U</a>
            <a href="#" rel="V">V</a>
            <a href="#" rel="W">W</a>
            <a href="#" rel="X">X</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Y">Y</a>
            <a href="#" rel="Z">Z</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you for providing a solution.